# Building a function to display of the sum of matrices at different powers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a for loop for the sum A+A^2+A^3+..+A^n.

Here is my code:

---

function [ x ] = Untitled2( A , n )

for k=1:n,

x =sum(A^k)

end

---

The problem I'm having with this is this function is listing the matrix A to each power without adding them.  What can I do to add these together?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's sum returns the sum along the first dimension not equal to one. If you want to add to x you would be best to use:

---

function[x]=Untitled(A,n)

x=zeros(size(A));

for k=1:n

x = x + A^k

end

Comment: This worked like a charm?  An additional question: how would this work differently for a while loop?

Comment: It depends on what your while conditional is, I assume you want to iterate the same way until your have reached n sums:

while k<n+1
x=x+A^k
end

Comment: @Heath Huffman If this answer sufficiently answered your question, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the side, and up-voting the question. Your answerers will appreciate it!

Comment: With that code on the while loop, I am receiving the following error: undefined function for variable 'k'.  How can I fix this?

Comment: First define k=0.

Comment: I got a recursive error.  How can I limit k?

Comment: k should stop iterating when k=n+1, what are you inputting for n? I do not mind helping, but @dinkelk 's suggestion is true and appreciated.

Comment: Done and done!  I ran the function for a 2x2 matrix and I let n = 4.  I'm not sure why it happened.

Comment: And here is the code for reference: function [ x ] = Untitled3( A, n )
x=zeros(size(A));
k = 0;
while k<(n+1),
    x = x+A^k

end

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to explicitly tell you to increment k in the while loop. After x=x+A^k, add a line that has k=k+1;.